# União de mais de uma tabela

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

No meu banco de dados há duas tabelas:

- cde_usuario
- cde_venda_detalhe

Começarei a introduzir uma parte de **Notificações** no sistema. O registro precisa ter alguma coluna que indique se a notificação foi visualizada ou não.

Então adicionei a coluna **notificacao** nas duas tabelas. Quando o valor for **0**, ela não foi visualizada, quando **1**, ela foi vizualizada.

Exemplo de registros das duas tabelas:

**cde_usuario**

```
| id | nome  | notificacao |
| 1  | Luan  | 1           |
| 2  | Carlos| 1           |
| 3  | Maria | 0           |
```

**cde_venda_detalhe**

```
| num_venda | valor | notificacao |
| 1         | 50.0  | 1           |
| 2         | 20.0  | 0           |
| 3         | 9.99  | 0           |
```

Fiz esta consulta para retornar os regitros que **NÃO** foram vizualizados:

```php
$sqlnotificacao = "SELECT cde_usuario.*, cde_venda_detalhe.* FROM cde_usuario, cde_venda_detalhe WHERE cde_usuario.notificacao = 0 AND cde_venda_detalhe.notificacao = 0";
```

Porém, sempre retorna apenas os registros da tabela **cde_venda_detalhe**, no caso a venda de número **2** e **3**. Gostaria de saber o que devo mudar nessa minha consulta para que também retorne os registros da tabela **cde_usuario**, no caso, a **Maria**.

Comment: Como as tabelas não me parecem estar relacionadas (pelo menos com o que você mostrou) me parece que uma possível solução seria utilizar UNION das consultas a cada uma das tabelas, contudo me parece que o resultado das consultas não são união-compatíveis. Talvez isto possa ser contornado se você acrescentar um campo valor contendo 0 na tabela cde_usuario e um campo nome contendo uma string nula na tabela cde_venda_detalhe.

Comment: Eu coloquei somente esses campos para ficar a pergunta ficar menos poluída, mas na verdade na tabela cde_venda_detalhe tem o campo id_cliente. Queria uma forma de fazer isto sem elas estarem relacionadas, aliás, futuramente adicionarei outras tabelas como por exemplo uma de tarefas e produtos que também tenho aqui.